# Treating columnaris in aquarium

Tags: aquarium

I have a 100L aquarium with 11x melanotaenias boesemani and 15x corydoras (5x each of bronze, pepper, julii).

A few days ago I noticed several patches of white film on one of the juliis and it seems to me that it's columnaris, based on extensive research on the Internet. This is what transpired after that.

Day 1: Detected disease on the younger julii cory that I got recently (more than 2 weeks). I could also see it on the upper lip of 3x of the boesemanis. I immediately started treatment with eSHa 2000 which was the only thing I had available - unclear whether it covers Columnaris.

Day 2: Applied second dose of eSHa 2000. After more research and speaking to some local stores, seems eSHa 2000 doesn't cut it. Added activated carbon in the tank for ~6 hours to remove residues, applied Baktopur which is supposed to cover it. Added eSHa OPTIMA vitamins. Turned on fans to keep temp down.

Day 3: Rest day on Baktopur treatment (as per instructions). Added vitamins and humin supplements.

Day 4: Second dose of Baktopur. Vitamins. Added 2.5 tbsp of API salt.

Day 5: The infected cory's film was growing larger so I gave him a bath in 5L with 15g API salt for ~30 minutes which removed the films but uncovered wounds underneath it. Placed him back in the main tank when he seemed to be panting. Added another 2.5 tbsp to main tank. Added Melafix dosage to main tank, vitamins and stress guard, after doing a 10% water change (kinda necessary because I removed water to give the little one the bath).

Day 6: Found slightly raised nitrates so added some bacteria. Added Melafix and vitamins.

Day 7: Still raised nitrates so did a 25% water change and filtered with activated carbon for ~6 hours as per Baktopur's recommendation. More of the boesemanis seem to exhibit the white lips. Corydoras seem oblivious (in a good way). Patient zero still alive but very weak and not eating.

I called several pet stores and vets and it seems that Kanamycin is banned in Europe for whatever reason. I wasn't able to find Furan on its own but it seems to be contained in API's White Spot Cure which I seem to be able to get.

I did however receive two other recommendations from a vet and pet store owner respectively:
a) Use [Flagyl](https://www.drugs.com/flagyl.html) (metronidazole), 500mg per 10 gallons.
b) Use [Trichosal](https://www.manaus-aquarium.com/trichosal.php) (copper sulphate, ethacridine lactate, acriflavine hydrochloride, methylene blue, magnesium sulphate
heptahydrate)

Overall, I'm pretty confused on the best route. Flagyl seems to contain other agents that sound toxic but I'm also weary that copper is very damaging to both plants and animals.

Any informed opinions to help? Photos below.

[image: Boesemanis with white lips]
[image: Patient zero julii]